# Manter valor de variável entre camadas de um função

Tags: javascript, html, variáveis, funções

Queria fazer um site em que quando clicar na imagem ela dobre de tamanho e largura, mas podendo fazer isso no limite de somente uma vez, e se fizer mais, apareça um aviso a impedindo. Da mesma forma, se ela estiver no tamanho padrão, você não poderá diminuí-la, e aparecerá um aviso, mas se você aumentá-la e tentar diminuir, isso será possível.

Eu parei no código por aqui:

```
function passar(img){
        var d = 0;
        if (d == 0){
        var x = confirm("tem certeza que deseja aumentar a imagem?");
        if(x == true && d ==0){
        d=d+1;
        img.height=img.height*2;
        img.width=img.width*2;
        }
        else if (x== true && d==1)
        window.alert("Não é possivel aumentar mais");
        else{
        var y = confirm("tem certeza que deseja diminuir a imagem?");
        if ( y==true && d==1){
        d=d-1;
        img.height=img.height/2;
        img.width=img.width/2;
        }
        else if(y == true && d==0)
        window.alert("Não é possivel");
        }}}
```

Meu maior problema está sendo que quando um `if-else` fecha a chave, o `d` não possui o novo valor que eu o dei `d=d+1` ou `d=d-1`, já tentei de outras formas mas não acho uma solução.

Comment: Tente usar `d += 1` e `d -= 1`

Comment: não pegou, continuou do mesmo jeito, quando fecha a chave do IF-ELSE o d(contador) perde o valor, ficando limitado ao proprio if e else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organizar o código sempre ajuda, está muito fácil se enganar onde cada `if` fecha, é um pesadelo dar manutenção em código assim, perdi vários minutos para entender o que realmente está fazendo e tenho minhas dúvidas se acertei. O nome das variáveis deveriam ser mais significativos. Não verifiquei se a lógica está correta.

Neste caso é necessário fazer a variável ser considerada de instância da função para seu valor mantido entre as execuções. Além disso só deve inicializar se ela não foi inicializada, por isso usamos um operador relacional

```js
function passar(img) {
    passar.contador = passar.contador || 0;
    if (passar.contador == 0) {
        var confirma = confirm("Tem certeza que deseja aumentar a imagem?");
        if (confirma && passar.contador == 0) {
            passar.contador++;
            img.height *= 2;
            img.width *= 2;
       } else if (confirma && passar.contador == 1) {
            window.alert("Não é possível aumentar mais");
        }
    } else {
        var confirma = confirm("Tem certeza que deseja diminuir a imagem?");
        if (confirma && passar.contador == 1) {
            passar.contador--;
            img.height /= 2;
            img.width /= 2;
        } else if (confirma && passar.contador == 0) {
            window.alert("Não é possível diminuir mais");
        }
    }
}
var img = {height : 10, width : 10};
passar(img);
passar(img);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/KeepVariableValue.js).

Deixei como contador porque pode no futuro querer permitir novas escalas, na forma atual, nem precisa ser um contador numérico, já que só tem dois estados possíveis.

Claro que existem outras soluções.

Comment: Então, eu usei seu método(dei ctrl ctrl v hehe) e não deu certo. Desculpe pela má organização, é que para mim assim fica mais fácil. Eu peguei algumas coisas como o "img.height *= 2;", mas ele não funcionou, todo o javascript parou de pegar.
Aqui o site organizado:
http://pastebin.com/brpgW2zi
( não pode mais que 600 caracteres, então mandei em forma de link )
de qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda ^^

Comment: Por força do hábito eu coloquei um `var` onde não devia. Agora botei um teste